# Thymeleaf and hibernate nested objects in form

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've got a user which references a country. All known countries are fetched and injected into the variable `${countries}`(these are properly displayed)

```
 <form data-toggle="validator" autocomplete="off" th:action="@{/registration}"
                          th:object="${user}" method="post" class="form-signin"
                          role="form" id="form-registration">
      <select th:field="*{country}" class="form-control" required>
                <option
                                        th:each="country : ${countries}"
                                        th:text="${country.name}"
                                        th:value="${country.id}">
                </option>
      </select>
```

For some reason my user does not reference the chosen country on POST callback:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {...
```

So it looks like thymeleaf is having problems to resolve the id into a country object. I refuse to write a wrapper for this simple use case. Any ideas?

**User**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
private Country country;
```

...

**Country**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "country_id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "iso_code")
private String isoCode;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="country")
private Set<User> user;
```

...

Comment: do you have reference from Country to User? I don't see it in your code. And can you post whole UI form which you POST then to server?

Comment: I had my relation wrong, but still it had to work with the relation being as it was. I added the form UI, the rest of the form isn't relevant and works perfectly.